# How to search Klipper

Tags: kde, search

How can I search through Klipper's saved clipboard history?

There doesn't seem to be any option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is there but quite hidden, you should just start typing and a filter box will appear, you can search through your history with that.

[image]

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=783927).